# bilinear form defined on $ X \times Y \to Z$ where $X$ is banach using uniform boundedness principl

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This question has a similar that was asked before, but it's not exactly equal. Please help me with this.
Let $X$ be a banach space, $Y,Z$ a normed spaces, let $B: X \times Y \to Z$ be a bilinear map, such that it's continuous in each variable, show that $B$ is continuous.

I tried to use the Uniform Boundedness Principle. For each $y\in Y$ the function $f_y:X\to Z$ defined by $f_y(x)=B(x,y)$ is continuous by assumption. Also for each $x\in X$ the function $f_x :Y\to Z$ defined by $f_x(y)=B(x,y)$ is continuous.

Since each $f_y$ is continuous $|f_y(x)|\le K_y ||x||$ and similar for every $x$ $|f_x(y)|\le K_x ||y||$

We'll use the boundedness principle on the family $f_y$ (since are defined on a Banach space). For each $x\in X$

$|f_y(x)|\le K_y ||x||$ But this I need a bound that depends only on $x$ and not on $y$

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the family

$$\mathscr{F} = \{ f_y : y \in B_Y \}.$$

By the continuity of the $f_x$, the family is pointwise bounded,

$$\sup_{y\in B_Y} \lVert f_y(x)\rVert_Z = \lVert f_x\rVert < \infty.$$

By the uniform boundedness principle, the family is uniformly bounded, i.e.

$$\sup_{y\in B_Y} \lVert f_y\rVert = K < \infty.$$

And that says

$$\sup_{x\in B_X,\, y\in B_Y} \lVert f(x,y)\rVert_Z = K < \infty,$$

hence

$$\lVert f(x,y)\rVert_Z \leqslant K\cdot \lVert x\rVert_X\cdot \lVert y\rVert_Y.$$